# How to return table with results

Tags: sql, sql-server

i am currently trying to write a function that will return a new table with 2 columns (val int, result bit). Val is value of SubTotal column from adventureworks db ( [https://www.innovasys.com/samples/dx/dx.db.classic/adventureworks_db~s-sales~t-salesorderheader.html](https://www.innovasys.com/samples/dx/dx.db.classic/adventureworks_db%7Es-sales%7Et-salesorderheader.html)) and result stores a bolean (if val is bigger than avg(val) it should return 1 if not then 0)

My function so far:

```
Create function [dbo].[GetAvg](@col AvgRes readonly)
Returns @ResultTable Table(val int, result bit)
AS BEGIN
    Insert into @ResultTable
        Select val, Case when val < (Select AVG(val)) Then 0 ELSE 1 end from @col group by val
RETURN
END
```

My table type:

```
Create type AvgRes as table(val int)
```

And how I use my function

```
declare @result AvgRes
insert into @result select SubTotal from Sales.SalesOrderHeader
select * from dbo.GetAvg(@result)
```

[image]

And this is result
So while SubTotal values sems right, result always return 1 no matter what subtotal value is. What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetAvg(@col AvgRes READONLY)
RETURNS @ResultTable TABLE(val INT, result BIT)
AS 
BEGIN
    DECLARE @avgval INT
    SELECT @avgval = AVG(val) FROM @col

    Insert into @ResultTable
        SELECT val, CASE 
                        WHEN val < @avgval THEN 0
                        ELSE 1
                    END
        FROM @col
RETURN
END
```